# What do the different Wield Styles do?

Tags: the-last-remnant

Depending on race and equipped weapons, characters can use various wield styles: One-Handed, Power Grip, Dual Wield, Two-Handed, Quad Wield and Dual Power Grip. How do the different styles compare and how should one choose which to use? Does the One Handed style benefit from an empty second hand, a shield or a second weapon?